# Can I perform this operation by one command?

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have two tables `table1` and `table2`. Both tables have the same structure. They have 4 columns (`x1`, `y1`, `z1` and `w1` in the first table and `x2`, `y2`, `z2`, `w2`, in the second table).

I want to extract values of the first column of the second table (`x2`). The procedure is as following:

1. Extract all rows from the second table for which `y2=y0` and `w2=w0`.
2. For every extracted row take values of the first three columns (`x_i`, `y_i` and `z_i`).
3. From the first table extract all rows for which `x1==x_i and y1==y_i and z1==z_i` (I know in advance that one or zero rows will be extracted).
4. For the extracted row (if there is one) check the value in the column `w1`. If it is not equal to `w0` add `x_i` to the list. If there are no rows extracted from the first table, also add `x_i` to the list.
5. Repeat this procedure for all rows extracted from the second table on the step 1.

In the end I want to have a unique list of values from the `x2` (no duplicates).

My question is if the described procedure can be performed by one command.

**ADDED**

`w0` and `y0` are known and fixed (just some fixed values).

Comment: wtf, where from do you have `w0` and `y0`? And, have you ever heard about joins? :D

Comment: and, for gods sake, replace raw with row!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an idColumn on table1 that will only have not null values. It will be used to test that the left join (which represents condition number 3.) actually produced any results or not. If any of the table's other columns does not allow null values, it can be used instead of idColumn.

```
select distinct t2.x2
from table2 as t2
left join table1 as t1 on t1.x1 = t2.x2 and t1.y1 = t2.y2 and t1.z1 = t2.z2
where t2.y2 = y0 and t2.w2 = w0 and ( t1.w1  w0 or t1.idColumn is null )
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! I understand most of the query command but I have some troubles with the last part of it. You say that "idColumn will only have not null values" and then in the command you have "t1.idColumn is null". So, I cannot understand how it can be null if it only has not null values.

Comment: @Roman, the null value would be induced by the left join. Check these basic details about outer joins on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join